# Dynamically populate multidimensional array for a jqPlot chart

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, jqplot

I can't understand why I have the following problem :

jqPlot allows users to submit a multidimensional array to provide X values and Y values like here:
PS: Sorry for the links, don't have enough reputation for images.

http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5286/vcZxOl.png

but in my case, I retrieve data with an ajax call and fill my array with a loop like here:

http://imageshack.com/a/img673/381/nSBDIP.jpg

I have verified with the debugger that my array has the same format that when it works:

http://imageshack.com/a/img673/6113/cE7uPO.jpg

So in short, it works ONLY when the array content is hardcoded.

Please, if someone has a proposition answer me. Thank you !

Comment: You don't actually state what your problem is.

Comment: The problem is simply that it doesn't work (the graph is not plotted) when I submit the 'lineWater' array that is populated by the loop (second link).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing the data(array) properly.

jqPlot expects the data to be an array of values.

Like in the first image: `[ ['1/1/2008', 42], ['2/14/2008', 56], ['3/7/2008', 39],...]`

You have already declared `linewater` as an array.
So I don't think you have to put `[] Square brackets` while passing it to the jqPlot `data` object.

`[linewater]` in your case is an array of array of values. So simple strip of the opening and the closing square bracket.

So in your code, instead of `$.jqPlot('eauChart', [linewater], {`

 Use: `$.jqPlot('eauChart', linewater, {`

And it should probably work.

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have tried to run without square brackets around 'linewater' and it only displays an empty chart with axis labels :
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/416/RXWiI9.jpg

That's really strange because data are correctly placed to match and plot the chart.
Note: before removing square brackets, nothing was displayed.

Comment: I think you have not included the required javascript files. Make sure you are including all the necessary files in the script tag: `jquery.js`, `jquery.jqplot.js`, `jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js`, `jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js`, `jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js` Or the minified(.min.js) files for the same.

Comment: I have included all required files and it still doesn't work :-(
Here is a code (from other project) that works and the array is populated by the same way: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/148/YeNWYG.jpg

I am lost :-/

Comment: Please post the snippet(the one that is not working) here. So that others can take a look at it. And try it out.